# Can someone explain the internal working of this program

Tags: java, string, hashmap

```
import java.util.HashMap;
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String s1=new String("ankit");
    String s2=new String("ankit");
    String s3=new String("ankit");
    // Adding elements to the Map
    // using standard put() method
    map.put(s1, "i");
    map.put(s2, "m");
    System.out.println(map.get(s1));
    System.out.println(map.get(s3));
   }
}
```

The out put is "m","m", I unable to wrap my head around how this is possible?,I understand the internal workings of Hashmap and string but i think i'm missing something here.

Comment: Since s1, s2 and s3 are all the same string, they return the same map entry when used as a key for the `get` method.

Comment: I recommend adding more `System.out.println()` statements. For example, add some after `map.put(s1, "i");` to see what is in the HashMap.

Comment: Read [`String#equals()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Also related, but not required to demonstrate this behaviour: [String interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

Answer (score 1):

The Java `HashMap` is a hash table of nodes that contain some key and value (i.e. `Node<K, V>`). When you `put(K key, V value)` into the `HashMap`, the following occurs:

1. `key` is hashed by calling `key.hashCode()`. The `hashCode()` method can be overridden in your class definition, or you can rely on the default implementation. For the `String` class, `hashCode()` returns the same hash for the same string (i.e. if the strings are identical, then the hash is identical).
2. Take the hash computed in step 1 modulus with the current size of the array backing the hash table (i.e. `key.hashCode() % buckets.length`).
3. Search the bucket indexed by `key.hashCode() % buckets.length` using the `equals(K other)` method for comparison. For the `String` class, the `equals` method returns true if and only if the strings are identical. Note that they do not necessarily have to point to the same `String` object.
4. If the node for the inserted key already exists, update the value. Otherwise, add a new node to the current bucket with the new key-value pair.

Now, `get(K key)` works the same way except in step 4 instead of mutating the bucket, it simply returns the value of the node if it exists or `null` if it doesn't exist.

**So What Does This Mean For Your Code?**

Let's walk through it. Keep in mind that identical strings yield identical hashes and that the `equals` method returns true when comparing identical strings.

1. All strings yield the same hash.
2. Size of the array doesn't change, so the index is the same for all strings. Meaning that we're going to search the same bucket in the hash table.
3. All strings `equal` each other. Therefore, we always find the node in the bucket (except for the first `put`).
4. The `HashMap` is now looking at the same node for all of strings. It creates the entry once, then every subsequent `put` is an update.

Using this knowledge, we know that your `HashMap` is treating `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` as being exactly the same even though they point to different objects in memory. This is because the `String` class defines `hashCode` and `equals` to behave in such a way. If you make your own implementation of the `String` class and don't override `hashCode` and `equals`, you'll get different results.

**Disclaimer**

This was a simplification of the `put` and `get` implementations, and I don't cover array resizing, the mutability of nodes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the indexing. You assigned the same value to the corresponding key, so when you

```
map.put(s1, "i");
map.put(s2, "m");
```

You are basically just doing

```
map.put("ankit", "i");
map.put("ankit", "m");
```

Which means you are assigning the node with the key "ankit" with value "i" then reassign the very same node with another value "m".
Also,

```
System.out.println(map.get(s1));
System.out.println(map.get(s3));
```

is really just

```
System.out.println(map.get("ankit"));
System.out.println(map.get("ankit"));
```

Which is just getting that same node but printed twice, which yields the result

```
m 
m
```

Finally, a side note here HashMaps are structures that indexes based on the key value, if I put the analogy of arrays, it is like a[0]="i", then reassigning that it to a[0]="m". Then printing a[0] twice just to see two m's

This is what the Badr B was trying to say in a nutshell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing s1.equals(s2) with s1 == s2,

HashMaps use 2 simple steps to decide if s1, s2 are the same key.
if s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode() && s1.equals(s2) then they are the same  and `map.put(s2, v2)` will override `map.put(s1, v1)`

again because hashmap does not care about their location in memory or if they are the same object or not, it just compares hash & equality.